# Pythonic way to filter list based on index

Tags: python, performance

I am wondering whether there is a pythonic way to perform the following operation on python list.
The input is : A large python list `demo = [1,3,5,...]`, a input index list index like `[0,1]` or `[2,3,5]` etc. 
The intended output for `demo = [1,3,5,6]` with index like `[0,1]` will be `[5,6]` with values in the index list filtered out.

A method I can think of is : 
python list comprehension like `[demo[i] for i in index]` gives the opposite `[1,3]` and convert demo and `[1,3]` to set and apply set difference.

I am wondering better solution with better performance.

Answer (score 4):

```
demo = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]
index = {2,3,5}
[value for i, value in enumerate(demo) if i not in index]
# [1, 3, 9, 13]
# Note that you can use a generator expression for a large list that you don't
#   require to be in memory all at once, e.g.
# (value for i,value in enumerate(demo) if i not in index)
```

You can also use `filter`

```
map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] not in index, enumerate(demo)))
# or map(operator.itemgetter(1), filter( ... ) )
```

Or even set operations, with some work....

```
correct_indexes = set(range(len(demo))) - index
[demo[i] for i in correct_indexes]
```

Comment: Sets are unordered, so for set operations example you'll probably want to use sorted(correct_indexes) which will hinder efficiency.